# How can I run multiple caller rights procedures with CREATE & GRANT statements using a single role on Snowflake?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

Let's say I have a few stored procedures on Snowflake to automate role creation and grants, schemas and so with CREATE ROLE, CREATE SCHEMA, GRANT statements.

If I wanted to create those procedures with Caller´s rights and have a single role to be able to run them (not using ACCOUNTADMIN).

I could use either SecurityAdmin or UserAdmin for role related procedures and Sysadmin for those involving creation of other objects, but I cannot create objects with SecurityAdmin and I cannot create roles with Sysadmin.

What would be a good approach, maybe granting GLOBAL MANAGE GRANTS to Sysadmin?

I know I can grant MANAGE GRANTS to Sysadmin either directly or through a custom role and in that way I'd be able to run everything through that, but is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not good practice to alter one of the standard roles. If they do not provide the permissions required for a specific activity then create your own role and grant it the necessary privileges

Comment: Would creating a custom role under SYSADMIN with MANAGE GRANTS be a great approach? Or where that custom role fit in the System defined hierarchy?

Comment: The role would need all the privileges necessary to run all the activities in all the SPs that you are creating. Where you create the role in a role hierarchy, or if you include it in a hierarchy at all, is entirely up to you - based on how you choose to manage roles, Snowflake’s documented best practise, etc